# Spring + Hibernate Not able to address issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

i am using spring 3.2.4 (latest stable version) with hibernate 
i have added all the dependencies but still i am getting the error which is below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor
```

if i use maven 
then i get too many errors like Failed to Autowired (in both service and DAO),

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider
```

please help me to solve problem for one of above.  i want to create an application (spring + Hibernate) any of way (with maven or without maven)

[image]

Comment: *i have added all the dependencies*: well, it seems you missed one or two. What is the list of jars in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The application is missing the `hibernate-core-x.x.x.jar` file.  You will need to find the appropriate version of the jar.

**Use FindJar:**  http://www.findjar.com/jar/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar.html

The class `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider` is included in version of Hibernate before version 4.0. I would update all of your libraries to use the 4.0 version.

Comment: i have used 4.1.9 final

Comment: Something is dependent upon that class from Hibernate 3.0

Comment: are you helping on first or second problem ?

Comment: snapshot i added is of the first problem

Comment: now getting this error 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Comment: continue on above 'Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class'